# qlpreviewcontroller navigation bar - How to Change "Done" button to "Back" or "Dismiss"

Tags: uinavigationbar, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

[image]

how to change the "Done" button title to "Back"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you change the navigation bar color?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

« Done » is shown if you present QLPreviewController. « Back » is shown if you push it on a navigation controller’s stack.

Comment: I've presented it....but still, is there any way to change the title to "back" or anything else? or is it by default?

Comment: No, there is no way to change it in the API. "Back" is usually expected by the user when navigating, so when the controller is pushed on a nav stack.